# How to convert int to datetime in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas DataFrame having the following structure:

[image]

where `time` attribute/column represents some point in time from which measurements were taken for a particular animal, denoted by `animal_id` attribute. The measurements were x and y co-ordinates represented by attributes `x` and `y` respectively.

I want to convert `time` from int to datetime format. But when I do the following:

```
data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['time'])
```

The output of:

```
data['time'][:10]
```

is:

```
0   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001
1   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001
2   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001
3   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001
4   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001
5   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002
6   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002
7   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002
8   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002
9   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

How do I specify two things in this:

1. Starting date instead of 1970-01-01 to say 2019-05-10
2. Specify differences between two consecutive times from the output in above to say differences between minutes

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) for minutes timedeltas and add `Timestamp`, because for minutes [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter `origin` and `unit` is not implemented:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'time':[1,1,2,2,3,4]})

data['time0'] = pd.to_timedelta(data['time'], unit='Min') + pd.Timestamp('2019-05-10')

data['time1'] = pd.to_datetime(data['time'], origin='2019-05-10', unit='s')
data['time2'] = pd.to_datetime(data['time'], origin='2019-05-10', unit='d')
print (data)

   time               time0               time1      time2
0     1 2019-05-10 00:01:00 2019-05-10 00:00:01 2019-05-11
1     1 2019-05-10 00:01:00 2019-05-10 00:00:01 2019-05-11
2     2 2019-05-10 00:02:00 2019-05-10 00:00:02 2019-05-12
3     2 2019-05-10 00:02:00 2019-05-10 00:00:02 2019-05-12
4     3 2019-05-10 00:03:00 2019-05-10 00:00:03 2019-05-13
5     4 2019-05-10 00:04:00 2019-05-10 00:00:04 2019-05-14
```

because:

```
data['time0'] = pd.to_datetime(data['time'], origin='2019-05-10', unit='Min')
```

> ValueError: cannot cast unit Min